# Toggle menu bar auto hide by pressing F6

Tags: applescript, automator, menu-bar

**My environment:** Sonoma 14.2.1 on MacBook Pro 14 (2021).

**What I wnat do to** is:

> (1) If I press the F6 key,
>
> (2) then DND is on, and at the same time the menu bar auto hide is on.
>
> (3) If I again press F6,
>
> (4) then DND and menu bar auto hide are off.
>
> (5) This have to work both in desktop and full screen mode.

**What I have tried** are:

(a). As a partial solution, I opened AppleScript and typed:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if autohide menu bar of dock preferences then
        set autohide menu bar of dock preferences to false
    else
        set autohide menu bar of dock preferences to true
    end if
end tell
```

But (a) is not good because this works only in desktop; that is, this does not work in the full screen mode.

(b). Another partial solution I tried is to use the Automator which runs bin/bash contaning the commands like:

```
(...some 'if' statements...)
defaults write -g AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen -bool false
(...and 'delete' in the place of 'write'...)
```

But this didn't make any change to my menu bar.

So what can I do now? Thanks to any helps and suggestions.

Comment: i'm looking for a list or documentation on the names of the panes or menus, but no luck - those I could find didnt work for me. can you share a link or anything? I'm trying to write a script that toggles the Fn / standard Function keys on off and then open some app. For example a script that launches the an IDE but before that toggles the settings of Fn / Function keys to be standard function keys. I also found a bunch of scripts but none worked for me (MacOS Sonoma)
Highly appreciated!!